# How to find what freezes Chrome when it runs an AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, performance, google-chrome, debugging, profiling

I'm inspecting a performance issue with an AngularJS application.

When performing specific actions, the CPU usage goes to 100%, the Chrome window freezes, and I have to manually terminate the process using Chrome's task manager.

I tried to debug the app (DevTools' *Sources* tab), but the application is quite large and the code is minified, which means that finding the issue won't be easy: I see a lot of code triggered by the digest cycle, and can't figure out which code is the actual culprit.

What could be helpful is to be able to profile the application once it freezes; I'm pretty sure the profiler will immediately show the actual bottleneck. I can successfully start the profiler (*Performance* tab) before the freeze happens, but once the application freezes, when I click on *Stop* button, the *Loading profile* window is stuck at zero percent (I waited for fifteen minutes just to be sure, it's still at zero), so I suppose that it's frozen as well.

Therefore my question is:

How do I find what causes the application to freeze when I'm unable to figure it out by simply debugging the application?

Comment: try detecting digest cycle calls with a [custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48661964/8495123). The common source of lag can be from [watchers](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef). Try detecting [a memory leak](https://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution was to **use a different browser**. Surprisingly, Firefox let me profile the application during the freeze. The remaining part was easy, as I expected: by comparing the profiling results before the freeze with the ones after it, one could figure which code is executed repeatedly.

Thanks to Aleksey Solovey as well for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670606/how-to-find-what-freezes-chrome-when-it-runs-an-angularjs-application#comment86351505_49670606).